# Using 'not only' and 'but also' - are both these sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, parallelism

I have searched so many sites and looked at the questions here but can't get clarification on whether both these sentences are correct or not. I've figured out they should be parallel and looking at them I think they are. However, I cannot find a sentence structured like this in any of the hundreds of examples I've seen.

The sentences are:

**I'm not only interested in soccer but also interested in hockey.
I am interested not only in soccer but also in hockey.**

This is the best explanation I found to understand the sentences but still not sure if both my sentences match.

The most important rule to remember about using this construction is that [A] and [B] must be parallel structures, in other words, the same part of speech, as in the examples above. In sentence 1, [A] and [B] are both nouns (string beans and broccoli). In sentence 2 they are both prepositional phrases, and in sentence 3 they are both main clauses.

1. Lily eats not only string beans but also broccoli.
2. The candidates campaigned not only in Iowa but also in New Hampshire.
3. Not only did Samuel start playing the piano before he could speak, but his mother taught him to compose music at a very early age.

If you have a niggling doubt about the balance of your sentence when using this construction, ask yourself these five questions:

1. ```
   Does each clause depend on each other to form a complete thought?
   ```
2. ```
   Does each clause use the same part of speech and tense?
   ```
3. ```
   Does my sentence make sense?
   ```
4. ```
   Does my sentence sound natural?
   ```
5. ```
   If I omit not only ... but also and insert and between the two elements, does my sentence still make sense? (Give this one a try with the examples above.)
   ```

If you can say ‘yes’ to each of these questions, you’re likely to have used the construction correctly.

So I think my sentence follows these rules. With no.5 looking like this:
I'm interested in soccer and also interested in hockey.

Then... I found this here as a suggestion when typing my own question:

"Earth Day deserves not only a commemoration, but also our total dedication."
This is correct here, since is perfectly maintains the parallelism. However, you have to remove the comma.

"Not only does Earth Day deserve a commemoration, but also our total dedication."
This breaks the parallelism, so it is incorrect. A better alternative would be "Not only does Earth Day deserve a commemoration, it deserves our total dedication".

As per question no.5 above… wouldn’t the following sentence make sense?
Earth Day deserves a commemoration and also our total dedication."

So I’m no clearer! I just can’t decide if it’s correct or not! Could someone please explain it to me.

Comment: There is no need to repeat _interested in_; the meaning is clear without that.

Comment: Thank you. But with 'interested' still in the second sentence can we say it is grammatically correct?

Comment: **I am interested not only in soccer but also in hockey.** is the best version.

Comment: Thanks again I appreciate your answer. I'm just wondering if it's 'grammatically' correct rather than the better answer. The better one indicates the other one is not incorrect?

Comment: It's better because 'not only' is closer to the first of the two parallel things (like the beans and broccoli). The first version is more comparable to Example 3 - the 'but also' could be a different phrase. **I'm not only interested in soccer but also a professional hockey player.**

Comment: Okay, yes that's clearer. So it is not as close and that makes it better. But is it grammatically wrong? Sorry to keep asking.. the reason I need clarification is due to a dispute in an exam situation. The teacher is saying it's wrong and the student is disputing it's not wrong and wants the required points in the exam. So it needs to be absolutely clear that it's either grammatically correct or incorrect. I can see how your last sentence veers from parallel but it's still talking about a sport and the interest in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130871/discussion-between-amarante-and-kate-bunting).